# Requirements for iOS game Development

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I've created apps using objective c. Now I want to develop some cool iOS games and I don't have any knowledge as far as game development is considered. So Can anyone please tell 
1) What are the basic requirements for developing a iOS game, and 
2) If possible can you guys suggest a tutorial to get started.

Thank You. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Cocos2d :-) http://www.raywenderlich.com/25736/

Comment: SpriteKit. See the WWDC videos for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Apple has brought their own framework "Sprite Kit" for making exciting 2D games I suggest you to go through [Raywenderlich Sprite Kit tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners),which I believe is an jump start for your consideration.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your answer...I've gone through the cocos2d documentation and also the sprite Kit documentation...and now I know what to do.